# Angular material directive not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc2/demo/fabSpeedDial

I'm trying to create a md speed dial with various buttons. However, it seems like the animation stops working as I add more buttons with ng-repeat.

This is my html

```
<div class="markeroptions">
        <md-fab-speed-dial md-direction="up" class="md-fling">
            <md-fab-trigger>
                <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                    <md-icon md-svg-src="images/location.svg"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-trigger>

            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button ng-repeat="mapoption in mapoptions" aria-label="Twitter" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
                    <md-icon class="locationicon" md-svg-src="{{mapoption.icon}}" aria-label="Twitter"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </div>
```

The speed dial opens correctly but when I close it I get this issue.

[image]

How do i fix this so the animation behaves like in the angular material design demo?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Need to wrap the contents within a repeat div.
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8079

Answer (score 0):

Yes, andrea is correct. Make it

```
<div ng-repeat="mapoption in map options">
<md-button aria-label="Twitter" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini">
<md-icon class="locationicon" md-svg-src="{{mapoption.icon}}" aria-label="Twitter">
</md-icon>
</md-button>
</div>
```